# Burning subtitles into video with ffmpeg with specific margin not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle, srt

I am trying to build a tool where people can position their subtitles on an HTML5 video and then I will burn the subtitles into the video for them.

I can easily get the position of the subtitles, in whatever format I need, that's easy. However, no combination of values that I feed to ffmpeg are working.

My holy grail is an x and y offest (aka offset 5% from the left, 10% from the bottom, in terms of video height/width).

To achieve this, I would like the subtitles to start in the very bottom-left corner.

```
ffmpeg -y -i english.mp4 -vf "subtitles=english.srt:force_style='Alignment=1,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,FontName=Arial,FontSize=24,MarginL=140,MarginV=0'"  -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output_video.mp4
```

Here is something that is approaching working, but it's behaving very strangely. The video is 850x480 but when I do a margin of 140 it goes way past the midway point of the video.

Am I missing something? How can I start the margin in the bottom left, and then apply the margin I want to push it away from the left and away from the bottom? I can do it either as a percentage of the video height/width if that API is supported or just pixels is fine too (but clearly doesn't seem to be working)

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the right hand side instruction, which maybe confusing things.
try:

```
ffmpeg -y -i english.mp4 -vf "subtitles=english.srt:force_style='Alignment=1,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,FontName=Arial,FontSize=24,MarginL=40,MarginR=140,MarginV=10'"  -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output_video.mp4
```

> MarginL. This defines the Left Margin in pixels. It is the distance from the left-hand edge of the screen.The three onscreen margins (MarginL, MarginR, MarginV) define areas in which the subtitle text will be displayed.

> MarginR. This defines the Right Margin in pixels. It is the distance from the right-hand edge of the screen. The three onscreen margins (MarginL, MarginR, MarginV) define areas in which the subtitle text will be displayed.

> MarginV. This defines the vertical Left Margin in pixels.
> For a subtitle, it is the distance from the bottom of the screen.
> For a toptitle, it is the distance from the top of the screen.
> For a midtitle, the value is ignored - the text will be vertically centred